# How can re-arrange the dates of the result according to the query

Tags: javascript, json

How can I organize the arrangement of months according to the query, I'm almost finish with my task, I already get the result of data by month but when I tried to return it, it's not being arranged.

This is the data I get,

```
"resultArray": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "colleges": "NO COLLEGE",
            "data": {
                "Dec": 4,
                "Feb": 3,
                "Jan": 19,
                "Nov": 29
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "colleges": "COLLEGE1",
            "data": {
                "Dec": 36,
                "Feb": 45,
                "Jan": 28,
                "Nov": 27
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "colleges": "COLLEGE2",
            "data": {
                "Dec": 8,
                "Feb": 62,
                "Jan": 50,
                "Nov": 62
            }
        },
    ]
```

What I did to get this data is used the reduce method first.

```
const organizedData = results.reduce((acc, { department, year, month, event_count }) => {
  acc[department] = acc[department] || {};
  acc[department][month] = event_count;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

And after that, I created another function that will map the `objects` and put an `id` on it so I can easily track it when I start mapping it on the front side.

```
const resultArray = Object.keys(organizedData).map((college, idx) => ({
      id: idx + 1,
      colleges: college,
      data: organizedData[college]
  }));
```

> http://localhost:5000/api/result/table?from=11&startYear=2022&end=02&endYear=2023&type=students

Now here goes again the query.

- from = `11 -> Nov`
- startYear = `2022`
- end = `02 -> Feb`
- endYear = `2023`

Now the result data should be arrange properly. According to their query.

```
"resultArray": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "colleges": "NO COLLEGE",
                "data": {
                
                "Nov": 29,
                "Dec": 4,
                "Jan": 19,
                "Feb": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "colleges": "COLLEGE1",
            "data": {
                "Nov": 27,
                "Dec": 36
                "Jan": 28,
                "Feb": 45,
              
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "colleges": "COLLEGE2",
            "data": {
                "Nov": 62,
                "Dec": 8,
                "Jan": 50,
                "Feb": 62, 
            }
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data on which you are performing all the operatios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple helper which sorts the months based on their respective query order to arrange the months in the `data` object according to the query. Something like:

```js
const getMonthOrder = (startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  return startIndex <= endIndex
    ? monthNames.slice(startIndex - 1, endIndex)
    : [...monthNames.slice(startIndex - 1), ...monthNames.slice(0, endIndex)];
};
```

And then to leverage it in your `resultArray`:

```js
const from = 11, end = 2; // This you can extract from url dynamically.
const orderedMonth = getMonthOrder(from, to);

const resultArray = Object.keys(organizedData).map((college, idx) => ({
    ...
    // Use it to set the value for data
    data: orderedMonths.reduce((acc, month) => {
        if (organizedData[college][month]) {
            acc[month] = organizedData[college][month];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {}),
}));
```

---

1. [Extracting `to` and `from` dynamically from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: It's working but the problem I'm encountering right now is it should be dynamic.

`const orderedMonth = getMonthOrder("Nov", "Feb");`

Instead of inputting the actual short name is it possible to get the `query` and then turn the`number` into the `text`?



`const orderedMonth = getMonthOrder(from, end);`

This comes from the `query`

Comment: @Stykgwar What should be dynamic?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally press enter.

Comment: @Stykgwar that you can mange easily ryt? Don't pass month there use the index directly. If the provided input is `1` for `January` and so on decrement an index and it will work